# ASP.Net C# Application does not send e-mails without default credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hello guys I have a problem in my ASP.Net project that is torturing me for like... ever! So my problem is that I can send an e-mail after the registration of the new user but it uses default credentials, even when I'm setting it to false. I don't want the new user to see my actual gmail or outlook e-mail I want to take this to a more professional level like "no-reply@imaginarydomain.com" or something like that. I'm not going to register to some webservice and pay a lot of money just to create an auto-responding e-mail which I will never check you know... Here is my Web.config SMTP code:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="no-reply@mydomain.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="My actual Gmail" password="My Password" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

and here is my code in the Registration.aspx.cs:

```
MailMessage activationMail = new MailMessage();
            string useractivation = "http://localhost:53631/Account/Activation.aspx?username=" + username.Text;
            activationMail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@mydomain.com", "My E-Mail Displaying Name");
            activationMail.To.Add(mail1.Text);
            StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Mails/ActivationMail.html"));
            string readFile = sRead.ReadToEnd();
            string Strcontent = "";
            Strcontent = readFile;
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[Name]", realname.Text);
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[Username]", username.Text);
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[Password]", pass1.Text);
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[useractivation]", useractivation);
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[Site]", "http://localhost:53631");
            Strcontent = Strcontent.Replace("[Facebook]", "facebook");
            activationMail.Subject = "Your Registration to ASP.Net website or something...";
            activationMail.Body = Strcontent.ToString();
            activationMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            activationMail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            activationMail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(activationMail);
```

If anyone has something please comment below thank you...

Comment: Well thanks that was usefull :) Do you know if the same thing goes for yahoo or outlook?

Comment: It's the same for any respectable email provider. The receiving server usually verifies the domain of the sending mail server against the domain oin the email. If they don't match, the receiving email doesn't accept. Or at least that's been my experience. By the way, most web hosting companies give you a free SMTP server.

Comment: Well thanks I will look into it :)

Comment: Yes they do but in php it is possible to send an e-mail even without setting an SMTP server... Is there some way to make this happen to ASP.Net too?

Comment: Hope that was helpful, I ll remove above comments and post as the answer.

Comment: PHP isn't magic, it has to know somewhere to send email to just like ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes but it only needs a "To" address and the "From" can be something that doesn't exist and it doesn't need any SMTP definitions and credentials... Isn't there a way to do it in ASP too?

Answer (score 0):

"no-reply@mydomain.com" must be a valid email. Gmail won't allow you to use an alias which does not belong to you or not linked to your account. 
Check [this link.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

It's a very obvious security concern where the providers cannot allow to send emails which are coming from an invalid/unverified email.

If you own the domain, I would rather suggest you to use something like [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/signup/?_ga=1.201236974.1546419422.1455257501) to achieve this functionality. You get a 12,000 free quota for free.